# Special Cells in Excel to Copy from sheet1 to sheet2 with error handling

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to Copy Sheet1 data to sheet2. I did handle 1004 error. If there is error, I want to open Sheet3  else copy data from sheet1 to sheet2. Please see my code. Truly appreciated for any help in advance.

```
Sub cmdButtonData_Click()

Dim SellStartDate As Date  
Dim SellEndDate As Date   

SellStartDate = Sheets("Launch").Range("H10").Value   
SellEndDate = Sheets("Launch").Range("H11").Value  
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear

On Error Resume Next  
'I have the connection string here.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
Else
    'Copy the data
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K2").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy 
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:T3").Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next ` is a sin and not error handling. Learn and use `On Error goto`

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are commented. On error Resume Next is one of error handling technique in VBA. Please click on the following link and learn more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement

Comment: @John that's not a VBA link, but VB.Net - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) is the link you were looking for. `On Error Resume Next` "allows execution to continue despite a run-time error" - which is why in most cases it's advised against. It's not immediately clear why you need it in this case.

Comment: Okay, Go through it. It has all error handling techniques for VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do an error check first to see if you have any results then you can move forwards. for example.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim c As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    If c = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Cells found -do something!"
    Else
        MsgBox c & " Blank Cells found- do something else!!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you count the number of records ? Failed to understand it. But thank you for your response.

Comment: Counting the cells takes care of the error trapping, if there are no cells, then c =0 but if c<>0 then you can move forward and copy the cells.

Comment: So for your example, if c=0 then you can activate sheet 3 or else do all that other stuff

Comment: Not yet working.On Error Resume Next
    Dim c As Long
    c = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    If c = 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
   Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K2").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:T3").Delete
    End If

Comment: I ran your code and it works, if the range is blank it activates sheet 3, if the c>0 then it performs the other lines of code. Can you clarify "Not yet working"?

Comment: I keep getting the error 'ERROR This Action won't work on multiple selections'

Comment: You can't use multiple selections, you can just copy the entire range.
`Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")`

Comment: Thanks much. Truly appreciated.